# Using `Euclidean Distance` to calculate total distance

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

I have a particle which is hopping between positions in 3D space

```
hops = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}
```

I wish to calculate the the total distance hopped.

Is there a good way to do this?

At the moment I have a `for` loop storing the total, which adds the differences like this

```
total = 0;

For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++ ,
  temp = EuclideanDistance[hops[[i]], hops[[i + 1]]];
  total = total + temp ; 
  ];
```

But, I wonder if I could do this better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Total[Sqrt[Total[Differences[N@hops]^2, {2}]]]
```

If performance matter then

```
Total[Sqrt[Dot[Differences[N@hops]^2,ConstantArray[1., Dimensions[hops][[2]]]]]]
```

is even a bit faster.

Generally, try to avoid `For` (`Do` is a bit better than `For`) for it is rather a top level construct in Mathematica.

Answer (score 6):

An alternate approach using [`RegionMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html)

```
hops = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}};

Total[RegionMeasure /@ Line /@ Partition[hops, 2, 1]] // RepeatedTiming

{0.00052, 3 Sqrt[3]}
```

The timing is much slower than the solution provided by [`Henrik Schumacher`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher)

```
Total[Sqrt[Total[Differences[N@hops]^2, {2}]]] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.000016, 5.19615} *)
```

**EDIT:** Another variation

```
Total[EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[N@hops, 2, 1]] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.000013, 5.19615} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`BlockMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html) and [`EuclideanDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EucledeanDistance.html)

```
Total@BlockMap[EuclideanDistance @@ # &, N@hops, 2, 1] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000061, 5.19615}

A bit slower than Henrik's solution

```
Total[Sqrt[Total[Differences[N@hops]^2, {2}]]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0000121, 5.19615}

Answer (score 2):

**Using `ArcLength`:**

```
hops = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}};
ArcLength@Line@hops
```

> 3 Sqrt[3]